# Elasticsearch upgrade from 1 to 5 - SearchRequestBuilder.setNoFields

Tags: java, elasticsearch

There used to be an API call in ES1 as

```
(new SearchRequestBuilder).setNoFields();
```

which 'Sets no fields to be loaded, resulting in only id and type to be returned per field.'

Is there a correesponding method in ES5?
(I hope also posting in the ES forum is not considered cross-posting)

Answer (score 3):

You can achive the same result using `SearchRequestBuilder.setFetchSource(false)`